# PHP refuses to run pm-suspend?

Tags: php, linux, root, sudo, suspend

So I've got a home server up and running, and have set it up with wake-on-lan, and had a friend manage to wake it from two states away. Great, that way I can run a file server without leaving it powered on all the time. Problem is, after waking it, I can't get it to go back to sleep. Certainly, I could configure it to suspend after x minutes, but then that would leave me buggered if I WANTED it on for some reason.

I've been trying to get php to run `pm-suspend`, with pretty much no success. I've built a script that I can run with `./script` from the terminal and it suspends fine. Php will execute it, it even echos the lines that I want it to, but it just skips over the line that suspends the system like it wasn't even there. Any idea on what I could do to make this work?

Comment: Why not just SSH in and run `pm-suspend`?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the server engine(apache/nginx) with the user root. `pm-suspend`need root permission.